# Отключении фоновой музыки в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

как отключить фоновую музыки при проигрыше персонажа, т.е. при столкновении его с объектом?

спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужен референс на `AudioSource`, который проигрывает музыку.

```
public AudioSource bgSource;
```

Далее просто останавливаем его в методе для обработки столкновения

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    // какая-то проверка, что столкнулся именно с препятствием
    // например по тегу
    // if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("obstacle"))
    bgSource.Stop()
}
```

Comment: Соглашусь с ответом luvjungle, но добавлю, что лучше не отключать музыку, а выкручивать громкость: `.Volume = 0f;`

Comment: Или можно поставить `.mute = true`